# How to terminate container-created threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am running a multi-threaded Java web application on Apache Tomcat 6. Instead of using the `new Thread();` anti-pattern, I leave thread instantiation to Tomcat (see code below).

I noticed in the last days that the web application gets slower and slower. After restarting the servlet container everything is back to normal.

Since I am not terminating threads after processing them (Don't know if I have to or if the Garbage Collector will destroy them), I am guessing that this is the cause for the performance loss.

The code basically looks like this:

**Custom Server Listener** (I added this to web.xml):

```
public class MyTaskRunner implements ServletContextListener {
  public static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR_SERVICE = ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(10000);

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    EXECUTOR_SERVICE.shutdownNow();
  }
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
  }
}
```

**Thread instantiation:**

```
for (Object foo : bar){
    MyTaskRunner.EXECUTOR_SERVICE.submit(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        doSomethingWith(foo);
    });
}
```

So, is there anything special that I have to do after `run()` has finished?

Comment: Maybe 10000 threads is a bit much?

Comment: that's quite the carpet you're threading

Comment: @sje397 First, I had the max number of threads set to 1000. After a while (1 day or so) the application stopped responding. Only a container restart helped here.

Comment: @Kublai I increased the number to 10000 and the app keeps working over several days but as I said, it gets slower and slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some basic facts about threads and GC:

- While a thread is running, it will not be garbage collected.
- When a thread is terminated, its stack is deleted and its `Thread` object is removed from the `ThreadGroup` data structures.  The remainder of the threads' state is subject to the normal reachability rules.
- You don't need to do anything special to make a thread terminate.  It happens when the `run` method call ends, either because it returned, or because it exited with an (uncaught) exception.

---

Now to your particular problem.  Many things could be causing your performance degradation.  For instance:

- Some of your threads may be getting stuck; e.g. waiting on a lock, waiting for a notify that isn't going to arrive, or just stuck in an infinite CPU loop.
- You may have too many threads running (doing useful, or semi-useful things), and the slowdown may be a result of lock contention, CPU resource starvation, or thrashing.
- You may have a memory leak of some kind, and the slowdown may be a symptom of your application starting to run out of heap space.

To figure out what is going on, you are going to need to do some performance monitoring:

- Look at the OS level stats to see if the application is thrashing.
- Use a memory profile to see if your application is short of memory.  If it is, see if  there is a memory leak, and track it down.
- Use a performance profiler to see if there are particular hotspots, or if there is a lot of lock contention.

---

I agree with the comment.  A thread pool size of 10000 is **dangerously large**.  It should be a small constant multiplied by the number of cores available to your application.

Comment: First, I had the max number of threads set to 1000. After a while (1 day or so) the application stopped responding. Only a container restart helped here. So I increased the number to 10000 and the app keeps working over several days but as I said, it gets slower and slower.

Comment: @valmar - increasing the number of threads is a band-aid solution.  The fact that it made a difference (for a bit) is evidence that your application's threads that are getting stuck.  Focus on finding what is causing that.

Comment: A cached thread pool might be worth considering if the number/rate of tasks isn't constant.

Comment: @Kublai Khan - that won't fix the OP's problem ... if it is what I think it is.

Comment: @Stephen C - yeah I didn't mean as a fix to the issue, just in regard to the last bit of your post - should've clarified

Answer (score 3):

Are you registering the context listener in web.xml correctly?

Does your run methods end at some point? or do they keep running indefinitely?

The ExecutorSerfice will simply call Thread.start for you, you are still starting threads from inside your webapp, which is not inherently such a terrible thing as long as you shut them down properly. No matter what tecnique you use, the execution of your run() method will not be truncated.

Comment: (1) Well, I simply added the listener like this: `<listener><listener-class>path.to.MyTaskRunner</listener-class></listener>`. (2) Yeah, the run methods should terminate at a certain point. If they don't a timeout exception is thrown (which terminate them as well).

Comment: @valmar - I suspect that your timeout mechanism is not working properly.

Comment: seeing also your comment about how raising the number of threads kept you application working longer, it seems to me as well that your run methods are not terminating how you would expect. A thread pool will exaust only when all the threads it spawns are alive and cannot spawn more, which means run methods not terminating. It would be better to have the run method perform a very short operation, with minimal timeout, and eventually enqueue itself again, so that the thread pool can eventually pipe them and have a possibility to shut down properly.

Comment: can't you use visualvm to look at running threads? or any other tool to produce a thread dump? or log the start and end of your run methods and then count messages to make sure all run methods that start also end?

Comment: @SimoneGianni Hm, the strange thing is: I fire an event after all threads have finished. This event causes a change in the UI so I am actually able to tell if all threads terminated or not.

Answer (score 1):

> new Thread(); anti-pattern

where do you people get that this is an anti-pattern?

anyway, 10000 threads is way too much. Each thread takes up memory and OS has its own limitations, so, as a safe path, try not to exceed a couple thousand threads.

connect jconsole (jstack might be enough) to see what your threads are doing - whether they're just sleeping, or waiting for something.

and it's not Tomcat who's managing the threads, it's ExecutorService inside java.